# Expressing a composite function with Taylor as a double sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, taylor-expansion

I was wondering about if, say you have: $$\arctan(\sin(x))$$ and you know the Taylor's series representation of both since $\arctan(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}x^{2n+1}$ and $\sin(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}x^{2n+1}$ then that you could do, *instead of the usual expressing the arctangent function as a series of sin, and that sin to be later expressed in powers of x*, if I could do something like this: $$\arctan(\sin(x))=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}x^{2n+1}\right)^{2n+1}$$ and maybe do some algebraic manipuations with the sums to get it easier, but I don't think that looks good or if it is already a thing, just a curiosity that popped out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [composition of power series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25182/composition-of-power-series)

Comment: You can certainly do this, but it is often difficult to "simplify" the complicated expression. It is helpful that $\sin(0)=0.$ It means the resulting power series $\sum a_ix^i$ has $a_i$ as the sum of a finite set of values, and thus you don't have to worry about convergence of infinite sums.

Comment: Indeed, it is difficult to even get things we know are true. If we know the power series for $f(x)=\log(1+x)$ and $g(x)=e^x,$ it is tricky to show $g(f(x))=1+x$ just using the power series. It can be done, but it is work.

Comment: By the way, you shouldn't use $n$ in both sum in the final expression. it risks confusion.

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula#Formal_power_series_version).